# When i am trying to configur sonar in windows i am getting the task execurion error

Tags: sonarqube

I am using Sonar-Qube-5.5 and Sonar-Runner-2.4. These are configuration that we have access to use. We need to do the set-up in each and every local system.

Added the logs for reference.

```
D:\sonar\sonar-runner-2.4\bin>sonar-runner D:\sonar\soanr_ws\FirstSonarProject -X
D:\sonar\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\..
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_79 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Windows 7 6.1 amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: D:\sonar\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.5
09:52:01.484 DEBUG - Publish global mode
09:52:01.562 DEBUG - cache: C:\Users\tcs_ban214.HDFCSLDM\.sonar\ws_cache\http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000\global
09:52:01.718 INFO  - Load global repositories
09:52:01.781 DEBUG - GET 200 http://localhost:9000/batch/global | time=63ms
09:52:01.859 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=141ms
09:52:01.890 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\tcs_ban214.HDFCSLDM\.sonar\cache
09:52:02.217 INFO  - Load plugins index
09:52:02.217 DEBUG - GET 200 http://localhost:9000/deploy/plugins/index.txt | time=0ms
09:52:02.217 INFO  - Load plugins index (done) | time=0ms
09:52:02.217 DEBUG - Load plugins
09:52:02.249 DEBUG - Load plugins (done) | time=32ms
09:52:02.249 DEBUG - API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin Git [scmgit] (built with API lower than 5.2)
09:52:02.264 DEBUG - API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin JavaScript [javascript] (built with API lower than 5.2)
09:52:02.264 DEBUG - API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin SVN [scmsvn] (built with API lower than 5.2)
09:52:02.264 DEBUG - API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin Java [java] (built with API lower than 5.2)
09:52:02.280 DEBUG - API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin C# [csharp] (built with API lower than 5.2)
09:52:02.373 DEBUG - Plugins:
09:52:02.373 DEBUG -   * Git 1.2 (scmgit)
09:52:02.373 DEBUG -   * JavaScript 2.11 (javascript)
09:52:02.373 DEBUG -   * SVN 1.3 (scmsvn)
09:52:02.373 DEBUG -   * Java 3.13.1 (java)
09:52:02.373 DEBUG -   * C# 5.0 (csharp)
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.732s
Final Memory: 3M/91M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: Task 'D:\sonar\soanr_ws\FirstSonarProject' does not exist. Please use 'list' task to see all available tasks.

D:\sonar\sonar-runner-2.4\bin>
```

Comment: Please apply proper text formatting in your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly executed the `sonar-runner` tool. You should execute command in directory where your project is located, example:

```
cd D:\sonar\soanr_ws\FirstSonarProject

D:\sonar\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\sonar-runner -X
```

Here is a whole documentation about how to execute `sonar-runner` from command line: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner